# How do i get my shape to move? I want it to move using the while statement provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, btms3, (250, 187.5), 125, 2)
pygame.display.update()

x=10
y=10
running = 1

while running:
  if x <=10:
    hmove = 1
  elif x >= 350:
   hmove = -1
  if hmove == 1:
    x += 1
  elif hmove == -1:
    x += -1
```

How do i make it do as the title says?
i do have the pygame flip and display update nd things like that but i could not show as i didnt want to have a super long code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the object in the application loop and you have to redraw the scene in every frame.Change the center coordinates of the circle in the loop and draw the circle at its new location in each frame:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((360, 360))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x, y, hmove = 10, 10, 1

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    x += hmove
    if x >= 350 or x <= 10:
        hmove *= -1

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, "red", (x, y), 10, 2) 
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

[image]

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)